# Android Dynamic view creation with view controlles at run time

Tags: android

I have a requirement where I have to show android activity contentview according to the json/xml provided by backend server. View will also content some button or Edittext fields so for example if the view contains user name field and password field then on button click one event should get fired which then call the web service and post the data.

So you can think of this as a template. The server will decide what template the activity should display and what should it do when some event gets fired.

Is there any native method for android to perform this kind of task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, NexusDialog is a library that allows you to dynamically generate forms in Android with little code. It's great for apps with many form-based UIs, since it reduces the boilerplate code to setup the view layout and tie things together in the Activity.

https://github.com/dkharrat/NexusDialog